# How to Trigger keyup event on Dojo?

Tags: events, triggers, dojo, arcgis, esri

I'm using Dojo in my aplication that uses the Arcgis Map Api.

I need to set the value in the Input text (Geocoder, widget from the API) and trigger the keyup event so the autocomplete would works.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/events.html

Comment: If I understand, you want to set the Geocoder's text value programmatically and then trigger the Geocoder's auto-complete based on the value you set. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to fetch the event like this:

```
 on(dom.byId("yourNodeName"), "keyup", callfunctionXY);
```

regards,Miriam

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to set the `Geocoder`'s text value programmatically and then trigger the `Geocoder`'s auto-complete based on the value you set, this seems to work:

```
var thePlace = "42 Wallaby Way";

//var geocoder is of type esri/dijit/Geocoder
geocoder.value = thePlace;
geocoder.inputNode.value = thePlace;
geocoder._autoComplete();
```